# Oxidation states of boron

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, boron-family

I have just been looking at      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oxidation_states_of_the_elements and found that boron has a -5 oxidation state. I would like to know which boron compounds form this oxidation state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I remember I have read somewhere that $\ce{Al3BC}$ is konwn to have Boron in -5 oxidation state.

- you can also reffer to this PDF page no. 139
  [PDF IN GERMAN](https://d-nb.info/995006210/34)

Comment: You are correct because (3*3)-5-4=0

Answer (score 2):

It isn't just boron.  The same Wikipedia list gives a -5 oxidation state for all the Group 13 elements except nihonium (which is only very recently known) and, more curiously, aluminum.  For thallium Wikipedia's article on the element gives [this reference](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic960014z), where a compound has thallium in various clusters and individual atoms bonded to alkali metals.  The individual atoms at least formally have five negative charges.

Comment: Except for Al, seemingly.

Comment: Said that, read again.